# Gulp and Pixi.js - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: gulp, pixi.js

I've recently switched to gulp and thought I'd try out pixi.js, I've been using the cdn of pixi but now I want pixi-timer to delay certain functions.

So I thought, why not start bundling all of it with gulp?

However I run into the following error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

I thought that the newest versions of pixi.js supported gulp and even browserify, however it fails as soon as I try to require pixi.js.

Got any pointers?

My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
 var PIXI = require('pixi.js');
// var timer = require('pixi-timer');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');


gulp.task('game', function(){
    return gulp.src('interface/js/gamelogic/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('game.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Vamp.Website/Resources/'));
});

gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.watch('interface/js/gamelogic/**/*.js', ['game']);
});
```

Full error log:

> D:\Stuff\Vamp\vamp\Vamp>gulp
>   D:\Stuff\Vamp\vamp\Vamp\node_modules\pixi.js\src\polyfill\index.js:5
>   if(!window.ArrayBuffer){
>       ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at Object. (D:\Stuff\Vamp\vamp\Vamp\node_modules\pixi.js\src\polyfill\index.js:5:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>       at Object. (D:\Stuff\Vamp\vamp\Vamp\node_modules\pixi.js\src\index.js:2:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>
> D:\Stuff\Vamp\vamp\Vamp>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

```
var PIXI = require('pixi.js');
```

Here you are requiring `pixi.js` during your gulp build. That's wrong for several reasons.

1. You are not actually doing anything with `PIXI` anywhere in your gulpfile. So why are you requiring it?
2. PixiJs is a WebGL renderer that's targeting browsers. Your gulp build runs in node.js which doesn't have a `window` object. That's why you're getting that error.
3. You want to bundle `pixi.js` and other files into a single `game.js` file. You don't need to require `pixi.js` for that. You just need to pass the path of your `pixi.js` installation to `gulp.src()` like this:

```
gulp.task('game', function(){
  return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/pixi.js/bin/pixi.js',
    'interface/js/gamelogic/**/*.js'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('game.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('Vamp.Website/Resources/'));
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, guess I still have a lot to learn :D Thank you for taking the time to explain in details